# How to find the accuracy of a simulated model with different datasets

Tags: java, validation, simulation, cloudsim

I am simulating my model using real 29 datasets. how can I calculate the accuracy of my model, based on the results obtained from these datasets?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a typical **Five Number Summary** **(min, Q1, median, Q2, max)** of the 29 datasets. Q1 and Q2 are basically medians of the datasets lower/higher than the median, respectively. Observe the numbers. If Q1 and Q2 have a relatively large difference, it means the datasets may not have a clear pattern, or you will need more data sets to see the pattern. If they have a small difference, however, find the result of your model and see where it fits. **The closer your result is to the median, the more accurate your model is.** You will need to revise your model though if your result falls outside the range between the min or max values.

[image: This picture is what the summary looks like]

Note: if your dataset contains more than one variable, simply repeat the process above for each variable and see how they fit together.